# iPhone - Unloading a cocos2d game that is running inside a View Controller

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

So here's the deal, I've been making a game based off of the open-source tweeJump as a small part of a larger application.

I have successfully gotten the game to load (from a tableView) and am able to play it, but I am not quite sure how to stop running cocos2d and return to the table view that starts the game. I have tried implementing a button inside cocos2d that stops the CCDirector, but that basically just freezes my application - I am not quite sure how to pop out the view Controller. I am not really that familiar with cocos2d, so I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Here's some relevant code:

The appDelegate (this does not run the game, but sets up the CCDirector for later use):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];

[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:YES]; 

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setPixelFormat:kRGBA8];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setAnimationInterval:1.0/kFPS];

[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888]; 

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Here is the relevant implementation for the view controller (which I load from a tableViewController) that's running the game, everything is in loadView:

```
(void)loadView{
if (!load) {
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
load = YES;
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] attachInWindow:window];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
CCScene *scene = [[CCScene node] addChild:[Game node] z:0];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: scene];
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you just make your TableView part of a separate cocos2d scene and then just switch scenes?

These are example methods I have in my application delegate that switch scenes:

```
- (void)loadGameOverScene {
    [_gameOverScene.layer.label setString:@"You Lose :["];
    [_gameOverScene.layer reset];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:_gameOverScene];
}

- (void)loadWinScene {
    [_gameOverScene.layer.label setString:@"You Win!"];
    [_gameOverScene.layer reset];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:_gameOverScene];
}

- (void)loadNewLevelScene {
    [_newLevelScene.layer reset];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:_newLevelScene];
}

- (void)nextLevel {
    [_mainScene.layer reset];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:_mainScene];
}

- (void)restartGame {
    _curLevelIndex = 0;
    [self nextLevel];
}

- (void)levelComplete {    

    _curLevelIndex++;
    if (_curLevelIndex >= [_levels count]) {
        _curLevelIndex = 0;
        [self loadWinScene];
    } else {
        [self loadNewLevelScene];
    }

}
```

Also, cocos2d has a menu system as well: CCMenu and CCMenuItem.

Here is a tutorial on how to use the different types of menus:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/414/how-to-create-buttons-in-cocos2d-simple-radio-and-toggle

I love Ray's tutorials.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I use this for opening GameCenter leadersboard inside cocos2d .

```
GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] 

    init];
        if (leaderboardController != NULL)
        {
            leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
            AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

            [[app navController] presentModalViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES];

            [leaderboardController release];
        }
```

Just call your viewController in place of leaderboardController it will work.